# Spring Boot Webclient - wait end response of multi call

Tags: rest, spring-boot, asynchronous, jpa-2.0, spring-webflux

I'm calling a rest endpoint multi time and save the response on a db with jpa. When all response are received I've to call a stored procedure in the database.

I'm trying to use web client to do this request but I'm not know how to wait/check all request are finished.

This is the code I'm using to call the endpoint :

```java
private Mono<DSGetDataResponse> GetData(DSGetDataRequest dataRequest){
try {
   return
    weblicent.post()
    .uri("GetData")              
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .syncBody(dataRequest)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(DSGetDataResponse.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
log.info("Sono in catch (Exception");
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
        }
    }
```

and this is the code I'm using to call the above method

```java
Items_to_request().forEach( x -> {
 String token = tokenResponse.getTokenValue();
DSGetDataRequest dataRequest = new DSGetDataRequest(token, this.Richista_DS(x), null);
try{
    this.GetData(dataRequest).subscribe(dataResponse ->   this.handlerGetDataResponse(dataResponse));
}
catch (Exception e)
{log.info("Sono in catch (Exception");
e.printStackTrace();
}
});
```

On handlerGetDataResponse I only save the response in the database.

How to wait all request are finished to call the stored procedure in the database?

I know I'm mixing no blocking call with blocking call

Do you have any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Thanks
Mirko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten your code using Flux

```
Flux.fromIterable(Items_to_request())
.flatMap( x -> {
    String token = tokenResponse.getTokenValue();
    DSGetDataRequest dataRequest = new DSGetDataRequest(token, this.Richista_DS(x), null);
    return this.GetData(dataRequest));
})
.onErrorResume(<add your logic>)
.collectList()
.subscribe(List<Data> data -> {< do what you want here})
```

You'll have to handle error properly using onErrorResume or onErrorContinue or similar operators or else flux will terminate. Check [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling)

This code will fire all the requests and collect the response into a list and then subscribes to it.

Comment: I think the subscribe call inside of the flatMap lambda is not needed

Comment: Yeah. I just copied whatever was in the question and forgot to remove that. Edited my response now.